# WPF application RESTSharp is not giving Result key word

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

When i got RestSharp package to my project it doesn't give me the key word "Result".I used (**using RestSharp;**) for the namespace.but it was like this why is it?
[image]

Comment: `Result` is a property of an `IRestResponse`, it is an `object`. To get the result, use `response.Result` instead.

Comment: Still i got an error under response.